# cakePHP PagesController could not be found after installing

Tags: php, cakephp, file-not-found

am very new to cakePHP and i am wondering why i get an errormessage that a Controller is not found, right after installing and creating the first controller via this [cakePHP Cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/articles-controller.html). 
I did everything as described with no errors on console or Web till this point.
On this tutorialsite there is a point where i should get some output after i created the "list template", which runs into an error in the WEB. [>see Image<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBXHj.jpg). After Downloading and starting the first run in the web, there is the fully functional website. But when i go on with the tutorial it fails.

Since the error occurs on the startpage with the "PagesController could not be found" and on the described index page with "NodesController could not be found" (i changed the name from articles to my project node name), i assume there are some problems with the basic routing cause the files are existing and the code seems to be correct.
I already found some stuff here and there via google, but nothing really worked. i also reinstalled cakePHP and all three times the same errors occurs. thats why i assume the problem with the routing.

But i cant find any idea where i can search or how to fix that problem. Thats why i am asking here.
If you need more information, please tell me, i will write when am back on.

Some information which might help for a answer:

- root server with PLESK Obsidian 18.0.32
- apache Webserver
- PHP 7.3.26
- cakePHP version 3.8
- installed with: composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:^3.8 ./ (as described in the first page of the tutorial)

thx in advance.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the routes that you've connected, the code that you've created, and the URL that you are invoking. From your image you seem to have changed the default application namespace (`App`), if so, then you must make sure that all the involved classes (controllers, models, etc) are using the new namespace (`Timeline`). The pages controllers ships with the application template, and by default uses the `App` namespace.

Comment: Hi ndm, thank you for your answer. i reinstalled it again, and configured the app.local.php settings. then i added the files like in the cake doc and it is everything working. seems i made a mistake as i changed the namespace for my own files. So now it is working perfectly, thx! best

Comment: If problem is fixed then please close it.

Comment: ok, but how can i close it? i read online, i just can do this, when i have enugh reputation...